# AJAX error function always fires

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I have a function that I want to use to process all my AJAX JSONP requests. It is working the way I had hoped, with the one issue that the error handler always fires.  The intended callback function DOES fire and gets the correct response from the server, but the error handler is firing as well.

```
function get_my_json(object_of_request_data,callback_function) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "myurl.com/getjson.php",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: object_of_request_data,
    jsonpCallback: callback_function,
    error: function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) {
      //textStatus is usually "parseerror"
      //errorThrown will say the callback was not called (even though it is)
      console.log("I always fire");
    }
  });
}

function my_callback(data) {
   alert("I get called before the error with a valid json object");
}

get_my_json({get_me:"some data"},"my_callback");
```

I could just ignore the error, but I'd like to fix it. Any ideas?

Most other similar topics/questions deal with the callback not firing, which is not the case for me.

Comment: Did you read the documentation where it explicitly says that the error handler does'nt work with JSONP ?

Comment: Aha, had missed that. Although it's strange that the error handler does fire, even though the doc says "This handler is not called for cross-domain script and JSONP requests.". So yes, taking out the error portion is equivalent to ignoring it.  Thanks for astutely pointing that out.